# Two-tier sorting for ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, sorting, angularjs-ng-repeat

For example, I have the following  collection used for ng-repeat:

```
$scope.pokedex = [{
  type: "Fire",
  pokemon: ["Charizard", "Moltres"]
},{
  type: "Rock",
  pokemon: []
},{
  type: "Fighting",
  pokemon: ["Machamp", "Hitmonchan"]
},{
  type: "Dragon",
  pokemon: []
}];
```

This collection will be churned out in a `ng-repeat` directive. In the actual application, the collection will be retrieved from a database, so it may be unsorted. I want to sort it in the following manner: priority sort types with Pokemon to the top, then sort each group by name.

**Edit**: I need to clarify what the backend data consists of. In the above example, `$scope.pokedex` consists of a constant number of types - these are categories. The application retrieves Pokemon from the database and fill up each category's list accordingly. The full range of types is intentionally hardcoded into the array and will remain unchanged regardless of whether the list of Pokemon in it is empty or not.

When the web page is generated using `ng-repeat`, the desired end state is as follows:

- An accordion is displayed with each type as a header, and the list of Pokemon in the body as a list/table.
- All empty categories shall be disabled but still visible, their headers given a particular CSS format, and all of them PUSHED TO THE BOTTOM beneath the non-empty categories.
- The empty group and non-empty group shall individually be sorted by category/type name.

Everything except the pushing of empty groups to the bottom and the sorting by name have been implemented. These are my final requirements to implement.

How can I do that? Is there a way to do it in advance, or via `orderBy` during `ng-repeat`, or any other workable solution?

Comment: you can use an order by query to order it coming from the database, you can also do it on the backend, and you can do it via the ng-repeat orderBy.  I would recommend doing it during the db fetch stage.  If I understand correctly, you'd want to get all people and first order by count(pokemon), then by person name

Comment: @holtc that is probably the desired solution, but it's currently still at a prototypal stage so there's no database data yet. I need a solution for use in the demo. I'll update this into my question.

Comment: If it's just a demo, you can always just put it in the correct order, since that is how, eventually, the front end will receive the data (cop-out answer I know)

Comment: Or try orderBy : 'pokemon.length' | orderBy : 'name'

Comment: @holtc hey sorry, I reflected on what I'm supposed to do and I think your suggestion is incorrect because I left out some key information. I've updated accordingly, please check! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You Can Try like this This

```
<ul>
<li ng-repeat="people in peoples | orderObjectBy:'pokemon':true">{{ people.name }}</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hey, I updated my question substantially, please take a look!

Answer (score 0):

**Please try the code below**

```html
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

        <div ng-app="myApp">
          
          <div ng-controller="pokemonController">
            
            <ul>
              <li ng-repeat="people in peoples | orderBy:['-pokemon.length','name']">
                
                name: {{people.name}} - number of Pokemons: {{people.pokemon.length}} 
                
                <hr />
              </li>
            </ul>
            
            
          </div>
          
          
        </div>



        <script>
          
          var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);
          
          app.controller('pokemonController', ['$scope', function($scope){
            
            
          $scope.peoples = [{
          name: "Obama",
          pokemon: ["Charizard", "Dragonite", "Moltres"]
        },{
          name: "Merkel",
          pokemon: []
        },{
          name: "Putin",
          pokemon: ["Machamp", "Hitmonchan"]
        },{
          name: "Kim",
          pokemon: []
        }];
          
            
          }]);
          
          </script>
```

Comment: Hey, I updated my question substantially, please take a look again!